# GIT Mudar de branch sem commitar ou descartar as alterações atuais

Tags: git, branch

Preciso enviar  minhas alterações atuais para uma outra branch.

Ao dar git checkout nome-da-branch ele me pede para commitar ou alterar as alterações atuais, não quero nenhuma dessas opções.

Como posso proceder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Caso queira deixar salvo as alterações efetuadas, você pode fazer um [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ferramentas-do-Git-Fazendo-Stash) e verá algo como:

```
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state \
  "WIP on master: 049d078 added the index file"
HEAD is now at 049d078 added the index file
(To restore them type "git stash apply")
```

, dessa forma será feito adicionado no `stack` e você pode efetuar o `git checkout` sem problemas.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Caso queira continuar as alterações salvas no `stash`, digite `git stash list` e será exibido algo como:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 049d078 added the index file
stash@{1}: WIP on master: c264051... Revert "added file_size"
stash@{2}: WIP on master: 21d80a5... added number to log
```

Então é só selecionar um com `git stash apply` para selecionar o mais recente, ou por exemplo para selecionar um stash especifico na lista:

```
git stash apply stash@{2}

$ git stash apply
# On branch master
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#
#      modified:   index.html
#      modified:   lib/simplegit.rb
#
```

Comment: Obrigada, deu certo (: